# Ionic 2 data binding on device

Tags: ionic2, 2-way-object-databinding

I want to disable buttons when fields are empty.

Template:

```
<ion-content padding text-center class="product">

        <ion-item>
            <ion-input placeholder="Product" type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.productName"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-input placeholder="Price" type="number" [(ngModel)]="product.price"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <button ion-button block (click)="checkPrice()" [disabled]="!(product.price && product.productName) ? true : null">Сравнить цену</button>

        <button ion-button block (click)="addToReceipt()" [disabled]="!(product.price && product.productName) ? true : null">Добавить в чек</button>
```

When I run this on browser - data binding works fine.

when I run this on device - data binding does not work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this using `<form>` and `required` in `<ion-input>` like:

```
<ion-content padding text-center class="product">
    <form #demoForm="ngForm">
        <ion-item>
            <ion-input placeholder="Product" type="text" [(ngModel)]="product.productName" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
            <ion-input placeholder="Price" type="number" [(ngModel)]="product.price" required></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
   </form> 
   <button ion-button block (click)="checkPrice()" [disabled]="!demoForm.form.valid">Сравнить цену</button>

   <button ion-button block (click)="addToReceipt()" [disabled]="!demoForm.form.valid">Добавить в чек</button>
```

Just an example. You need to check other parts/conditions in your code if you have any.